# Constant feed of ^@ at prompt

Tags: ubuntu, drivers

I installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu server 17.10 on an older Core 2 Duo machine. Installation went without a hitch. When I start up though, I'm getting a non-stop series of `^@` entered into the prompt at about one every 750 ms. I didn't have this problem during the installation.

I have no idea where they come from; I tried unplugging all USB devices - no change. Tried unplugging front connectors - no change. I can't even login right now - I can't type my username fast enough to fit in the 750ms window.

Any idea what's going on?